# How can I make a Redis event on ElastiCache trigger a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda

I have a small function I want to move from a dedicated EC2 instance to Lambda. This function is currently triggered by a broadcast from a Redis instance in ElastiCache. How can I make a Redis broadcast trigger a lambda function?

Someone frome AWS said that this could be done through CloudWatch, but the only ElastiCache event I can find is "AWS API Call via CloudTrail".

Answer (score 2):

If your use Redis as a queue, try SQS instead. SQS can trigger Lambda. ElastiCache doesn't create events or log entries similar to broadcast events.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I'm worried about the amount of overhead involved in that kind of transition.